Best Practices for Closing a Modal Popup Programmatically in Aura Component Integration
I'm working with a managed package and would like to understand the best practices for implementing the request.
Background
We have an Aura component where we invoke an Aura or LWC component (using createComponent)  from the Subscriber org, which is working fine. I've used overlayLib to display the component in a modal popup.
Need Suggestion
At the final stage, when the Subscriber completes all tasks in that component, I need a way to trigger a function or event from their component to notify my component, allowing me to close the modal popup programmatically without requiring manual interaction with the close icon.
$A.createComponent( 
                action, params,
                function(components, status, errorMessage){
                    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                        const modalComponent = component.find('overlayLib');
                        if (modalComponent != null) {
                            modalComponent.showCustomModal({
                                body: components,
                                showCloseButton: true,
                                cssClass: "slds-modal_large",
                                closeCallback: function() { //closing Modal popup Manually
                                    component.set('v.dynamicComponent', '');
                                    const cmpEvent = component.getEvent("closeMyModalEvent"); //My message passing channel to parent component
                                    cmpEvent.setParams({
                                        message: "ModalClosed!"
                                    });
                                    cmpEvent.fire();
                                }
                            }).then(function(modal) {
                                component.set('v.dynamicComponent', modal);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                        
                    }
                    else if (status === "ERROR") {
                        console.error("Error creating dynamic component: " + errorMessage);
                        $A.createComponent(
                            'lightning:formattedRichText',
                            {
                                value: 'Something went wrong. Please contact Administrator',
                                class: 'slds-text-heading_medium',
                            },
                            function(formattedRichText, sts, errormsg){
                                if (sts === "SUCCESS") {
                                    const modalComponent = component.find('overlayLib');
                                    if (modalComponent != null) {
                                        modalComponent.showCustomModal({
                                            body: formattedRichText,
                                            showCloseButton: true,
                                            cssClass: "slds-modal_large",
                                        }).then(function(modal) {
                                            component.set('v.dynamicComponent', modal);
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
        );


Does this help? The person asking has posted an answer and succeeded, apparently.

@FelixvanHove - In my case I don't have any issue with API version, I just want to understand the best practice to close the modal popup programmatically,  using Platform Event or Message passing or Component event.
